# Passport local strategy is never get called

Tags: express, passport.js, passport-local

I know this question was asked many times in stack over flow. I tried every accepted answers but can't my local strategy into function. Here is my code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
app.set('trust proxy', 1); // trust first proxy
app.use(session({
  secret: '564sdf4as564f56a7s765s4afjkgadxjkbadksj',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  cookie: { secure: true }
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField:'userName',
  passwordField:'password',
  passReqToCallback : true 
},function(request, userName, password, done) {
  console.log(request);
  UserAccount.findOne({'userName': userName} , function(err, user) {
    if (err) return done(err);
    if (!user) return done(null, false, 'Incorrect username.' );
    user.verifyPassword(password, function(err, isMatch) {
      if (isMatch) {
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        return done(null, false, 'Incorrect password.');
      }
    });
  });
}));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  console.log('Serialize user called');
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  console.log('Deserialize user called');
  UserAccount.findById(id, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

Then I created a router like

```
var router = express.Router();
require('./controllers/user')(router,passport);
app.use('/api',router);
```

Then in my user controller I created signIn function like

```
app.post('/signIn',function (request,response,next){
        var variables = request.body;
        console.log(variables);
        passport.authenticate('local', function(error, user, info) {
            console.log(user);
            if (error) { console.log(error); return next(err); }
            if (!user) { return response.redirect('/login'); }
            response.logIn(user, function(err) {
              if (err) { return next(err); }
              return response.redirect('/users/' + user.username);
            });
        })(request, response, next);
    });
```

Then I send a request from "Postman"

```
{
    "userName":"karthik@abc.com",
    "password":"qwerty"
}
```

My mongodb userName and password fields are same.

In my db there is an account with this user name and password. But every time it return 'user' as 'false' inside authenticate. I tried to console my request inside local strategy but it never gets called. I don't understand What I done wrong here? Can some one help to solve this? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should name local strategy and use it in authenticate. 
Use like this `passport.use('local-strategy',new LocalStrategy({});`
and like `passport.authenticate('local-strategy');`